# Reasons for git commit failure (exiting with non-zero)

Tags: bash, git

Besides the case where no files are staged for commit, is there any other reason why a `git commit` command would exit with non-zero? I don't have an error to show, I just am writing a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

git commit -m "foo" || {
  echo "could not create new commit, no big deal"
}

## keep going with muh script
```

Basically I am looking to know if there is an exit code or check I should make in case a problem that prevents a commit is serious enough to stop my script for.

Comment: Maybe if your branch is in the middle of a merge or rebase, a commit attempt would fail.  Can you give us context for which the above script is failing?

Comment: Nah script is not failing now, I am just curious about handling certain edge cases that I haven't encountered yet. Currently if I can't make a commit, it's fine because I assume the reason is b/c I have no changes to commit, but that's a big assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Besides [the case Tim Biegeleisen mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53110958/reasons-for-git-commit-failure-exiting-with-non-zero#comment93117017_53110958)—`git commit` when the index has unmerged files—`git commit` can fail in a number of additional cases:

- A pre-commit hook exits nonzero, aborting the commit.  (The user can skip the pre-commit hook using `--no-verify` but your script does not use `--no-verify`.)
- Something else goes very wrong, e.g., the entire file system has gone read-only for some reason (Linux will freeze a file system into read-only state on certain hardware failures, for instance).
- The commit actually succeeded, but a post-commit hook exited nonzero: if there is a post-commit hook, its exit status becomes the exit status of `git commit`.  (This is arguably a bug in Git as the documentation claims that a post-commit hook cannot affect the outcome of `git commit`.  Does *outcome* here mean *generated commit* only, or should it include the command's exit status?)

Comment: Well, bonus points if there is a --no-verify that applies to git post-commit?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no equivalent to `--no-verify` for the post-commit hook. I think this is a bug, but if the Git people feel that the exit status of the post-commit hook *should* be reflected, that makes it a documentation bug, rather than a code bug: the githooks man page should say "cannot affect whether the commit is made, but does set the exit status".

Comment: you should tell them - I am sure you have a communication channel going, but in the unlikely case, it's `git@vger.kernel.org`